# core data contains null entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Within my core data fetchRequest, some of the entries returned contain nothing but null, yet I don't see any errors when I go to save my data. I am trying to figure out what is even causing this problem in the first place.

Here is my code for first fetching the data and saving it

```
- (IBAction)getCaredBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://netrunnerdb.com/api/cards/"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError){
            NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            //Array that contains parsed JSON data
            for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray){
                CorpCard *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CorpCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                if ([[dict objectForKey:@"side"] isEqualToString:@"Corp"] && ![[dict objectForKey:@"setname"] isEqualToString:@"Special"]){
                    newEntry.type = [dict objectForKey:@"type"];
                    newEntry.title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
                    newEntry.text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
                    newEntry.subtype = [dict objectForKey:@"subtype"];
                    newEntry.faction = [dict objectForKey:@"faction"];
                    newEntry.influence = [dict objectForKey:@"factioncost"];
                    newEntry.unique = [dict objectForKey:@"uniqueness"];
                    newEntry.limit = [dict objectForKey:@"limited"];


                    //Add the entries to our database
                    if([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Identity"]){
                         newEntry.influence =[dict objectForKey:@"influencelimit"];
                        newEntry.minDeckSize =[dict objectForKey:@"minimumdecksize"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }


                    }
                    if([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Agenda"]) {
                        newEntry.cost = [dict objectForKey:@"advancementcost"];
                        newEntry.agendaPoint = [dict objectForKey:@"agendapoints"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }


                    }
                    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Operation"]){
                        newEntry.cost = [dict objectForKey:@"cost"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }


                    }
                    if([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"ICE"]){
                        newEntry.cost = [dict objectForKey:@"cost"];
                        newEntry.strength = [dict objectForKey:@"strength:"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }


                    }
                    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Asset"]){
                        newEntry.cost = [dict objectForKey:@"cost"];
                        newEntry.trashCost = [dict objectForKey:@"trash"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }


                    }
                    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Upgrade"]){
                        newEntry.cost = [dict objectForKey:@"cost"];
                        newEntry.trashCost = [dict objectForKey:@"trash"];
                        NSError *error;
                        if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                            NSLog(@"Error occured, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        }
                    }
                    NSLog(@" added: %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", [dict objectForKey:@"title"], [dict objectForKey:@"trash"], [dict objectForKey:@"cost"], [dict objectForKey:@"text"], [dict objectForKey:@"faction"], [dict objectForKey:@"type"]);

                }
            }   
        }            
    }];

}
```

Here is my code for fetching the data

```
- (IBAction)prntCardsBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    //print out entries of our database
    AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.corpCards = [delegate getAllCorpCards];
    int i;

    for (i =0; i <self.corpCards.count;i++){
         CorpCard *card = [self.corpCards objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", card.title, card.text, card.type);
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the method that executes the fetch that is called within the delegate.

```
-(NSArray *)getAllFactionCards:(NSString *)faction{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:faction inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *cards = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    return cards;
}
```

Lastly, here is a snipet from the dub. Not every entry is returning null

```
2014-09-01 18:06:33.780 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.782 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.783 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.783 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.784 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.784 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Melange Mining Corp., [Click], [Click], [Click]: Gain 7[Credits]., Asset
2014-09-01 18:06:33.785 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.785 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.786 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.786 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Scorched Earth, Play only if the runner is tagged.

Do 4 meat damage., Operation
2014-09-01 18:06:33.787 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Private Security Force, If the Runner is tagged, Private Security Force gains: "[Click]: Do 1 meat damage.", Agenda
2014-09-01 18:06:33.787 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Adonis Campaign, Put 12[Credits] from the bank on Adonis Campaign when rezzed. When there are no credits left on this card, trash it.

Take 3[Credits] from Adonis Campaign when your turn begins., Asset
2014-09-01 18:06:33.789 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.790 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.790 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Eli 1.0, The Runner may spend [Click] to break any subroutine on Eli 1.0.

[Subroutine] End the run.

[Subroutine] End the run., ICE
2014-09-01 18:06:33.791 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.791 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Haas-Bioroid: Engineering the Future, The first time you install a card each turn, gain 1[Credits]., Identity
2014-09-01 18:06:33.792 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] NBN: Making News, 2[Recurring Credits]

Use these credits during trace attempts., Identity
2014-09-01 18:06:33.792 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.792 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] (null), (null), (null)
2014-09-01 18:06:33.793 NetrunnerApp[2205:60b] Jinteki: Personal Evolution, Whenever an agenda is scored or stolen, do 1 net damage., Identity
```

Comment: How are you calling "getAllCorpCards" on your application delegate?

Comment: also, for neatnesses you can replace "[dict objectForKey:@"type"];" with dict[@"type"];

Comment: getAllCorpCards just passes CorpCards for the faction string. The purpose of the method is the be able to get any entity and just change the string name around.

Comment: also, you use getAllCorpCards but then highlight 'getAllFactionCards' from your delegate

Comment: Do you have any validation rules set in the model? What merge policy are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here -

```
  for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray){
      CorpCard *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CorpCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
      if ([[dict objectForKey:@"side"] isEqualToString:@"Corp"] && ![[dict objectForKey:@"setname"] isEqualToString:@"Special"]){
```

You are creating a new entry in the object context, but then you check values in your dictionary to see if you should populate it.  Even if you don't populate it, the new object is still sitting there in your managed object context waiting for the next call to `save`.

You simply need to restructure the start of your loop -

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dataArray) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"side"] isEqualToString:@"Corp"] && ![[dict objectForKey:@"setname"] isEqualToString:@"Special"]) {
         CorpCard *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CorpCard" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

So that you only create the new object when you need one.